# Why is `puts minus(start - 1)` outputs ` ` and `p minus(start - 1)` outputs `nil`?

Tags: ruby, recursion

I know the following recursion example works properly as `minus(start - 1)`.  However I'm trying to understand why the adding a `puts` outputs   and `p` outputs `nil`.

If my understanding is correct the recursion starts with the last stack frame pushed, which would evaluate to 2, then 1, then 0.  Does this have to do with outputting an expression that has no definite value?

```
def minus(start)
  puts start
  if start > 0
    puts minus(start - 1)
  end
end

minus(3)
3
2
1
0
```

Comment: Why do you have two `puts` / `p` in the first place? You're outputting both, the current value (`puts start`) and the next recursion's result (`puts minus(start - 1)`). Is that intended? If so, what is your expected result?

Comment: This isn't my code.  I came across this from someone else, understood there is a superfluous `puts` and that `puts` does not return a value, but am trying to understand why the output of the recursion `minus(start - 1)` is evaluating to `nil`.  I think that I'm not explaining myself very well though.

Comment: Maybe this helps: `puts obj` prints `obj` and returns `nil` whereas `p obj` prints `obj` and returns `obj`. (in addition the former uses `to_s` and the latter uses `inspect` but for integers the output is identical)

Comment: In general, mixing computation and output is rarely a good idea / design. It would be much cleaner to have the method _return_ an array or _yield_ its values, e.g. `minus(3) { |i| puts i }`

Comment: Why does `minus(start-1)` return `nil`?

Comment: Because `puts …` is the last expression evaluated in the method and `puts` _always_ has a return value of `nil`. Again: output ≠ return value.

Comment: If `'puts` is replaced by `p`, `p` also returns `nil`.  `p` returns the evaluated expression, in this case `minus(start - 1)`.  So that implies `minus(start - 1)` evaluates to `nil`.  I don't understand why that last sentence is true.

Comment: If `start` is `0` at the last step of the recursion, the `if` expression will evaluate to `nil`, because there's no `else` block. Adding `else 0` would provide a default / base value for the recursion.

Answer (score 3):

It is because how `puts` and `p` works.

When we use `puts` it calls `to_s` from the object.

When we use `p` it calls `inspect` from the object.

With `nil`:

```rb
nil.to_s # ''
nil.inspect # 'nil'
```

```rb
puts nil # It will use to_s and the result will be ''
p nil # It will use inspect and the result will be 'nil'
```

Comment: For `minus(3)`, the first iteration of `minus(start-1)` evaluates as 2.  So why is `puts minus(start-1)` outputting ` ` instead of `2`?

Comment: @5pacemanSpiff `puts minus(start-1)` prints the result of `minus(start-1)` which is `nil` (having a `to_s` value of `''`). Maybe you are confusing the output of a `minus(start-1)` with its return value.

Answer (score 2):

When there is no explicit `return` in Ruby then a method returns the value returned by the last expression in the method.

The return value of the expression `minus(start - 1)` would be whatever is returned by the `minus` method.

But the return value of `puts minus(start - 1)` would always be `nil` because that is how the `puts` method is specified. Quote from the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/IO.html#method-i-puts):

> `puts(obj, ...)` → `nil``
>
> Writes the given object(s) to *ios*. Writes a newline after any that do not already end with a newline sequence. Returns `nil`.

That said because the return value of all recursive calls to `minus` is `nil`  in your examples this `nil` is outputted. And – as rowend already explained – `puts nil` calls `to_s` on `nil` and therefore outputs an empty string. Whereas `p` calls `inspect` on the `nil` and therefore outputs `nil`.

Comment: Additionally `if start >0` only has a true path therefor when `start = 0` as a result of the final recursion `nil` will always be the result here as well.